# Basis for lie algebra sl(n,F) : $\mathfrak{sl}(2,F)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, problem-solving, semisimple-lie-algebras

$\mathfrak{sl}(2,F)$ is lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(2,F)$.
Let $x=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1\\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}$, $h=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0\\ 0&-1 \end{pmatrix}$
$y=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &0\\ 1&0 \end{pmatrix}$.

I understand $\{x,y,z \}$  forms a basis for $\mathfrak{sl}(2,F)$ and had found the structure constants.

I have following urging questions. Please help me with this.

1. Why people specifically working on this basis?
2. Is there a similar ordered basis for $\mathfrak{sl}(n,F)$?
3. Suggest me some good set of problems on basic lie algebra to practice.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Question 1:* This basis fits to the general theory of semisimple Lie algebras. Namely, $x$ and $y$ are nilpotent, with $x\in \mathfrak{n}^+$ and $y\in \mathfrak{n}^-$, for $\mathfrak{n}$ the nilradical of the standard Borel subalgebra, and $h\in \mathfrak{h}$ is diagonal. So $$\mathfrak{sl}_2(F)=\mathfrak{n}^-\oplus \mathfrak{h}\oplus \mathfrak{n}^+$$

*Question 2:* Yes, there is a similar one for $\mathfrak{sl}_n(F)$, where the diagonal matrices span the Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$.

*Question 3:* Indeed, take the problems of Humphrey's book. Solutions are even online (see for example [here](https://docplayer.net/59920605-Solutions-to-some-exercises-in-the-book-j-e-humphreys-an-introduction-to-lie-algebras-and-representation-theory.html)).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't know about Borel subalgebra and Cartan subalgebra. I will explore this.